# Is there always a bijection between a fiber bundle and the cartesian product?

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

It's well known that there are non-trivial bundles such as the Mobius strip. In these cases it is known the bundle $E$ with bundle map $\pi : E \to B$ over base space $B$ with fiber $F$ cannot be expressed as $E = B \times F$. This is because the topology of $E$ and $B$ might be such that the map $\pi$ is not continuous as it needs to be for a bundle map if $E$ is $B\times F$ endowed with the usual product topology.

However, can it be shown that bundle $E$ over base space $B$ with bundle $F$ always has a bijection with $B\times F$, ignoring topology/continuity? I'm wondering if a bundle can, in general be written as $E=B\times F$, but with the understanding that the topology on $E$ is NOT the product topology that would typically come with $B\times F$.

Comment: Yes, at least assuming the axiom of choice. But why would you want to do so?

Comment: @MoisheKohan For fun? I guess for the sake of intuition. I guess people are always quick to point out that $E\not= B\times F$, but maybe for some it would be intuitive to say $E$ can be always thought of as $B\times F$ but sometimes (in the non-trivial case) with a different topology than the product topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noncontinuous bijections we have
$$E=\bigcup_{b\in B}\pi^{-1}(b)\cong \bigcup_{b\in B}F\cong B\times F.$$

The following turns out to be useful in the homotopical classification of locally trivial bundles with fixed fibre.

**Application**: The collection of isomorphism classes of bundles over $B$ with fibre $F$ forms a set (and not a proper class).

**Proof**: The total space $E$ of any $F$-bundle over $B$ is homeomorphic to a space whose underlying set is $B\times F$. But the family of all topologies on any given set is a set. For any one of these topologies one may need to consider different projections $E\rightarrow B$, but there is again only a set of these. Finally, a set-indexed union of sets is a set. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: I guess those are disjoint union symbols?

Comment: The first one is just the union of the subspaces of $E$, but you're right @Jagerber48, the second one should be a disjoint union.

Comment: You may want to make the dependence of this proof on the axiom of choice more explicit.

Comment: @MoisheKohan where is axiom of choice needed? Is it needed to show E has a bijection with BxF or just needed for the application? Or both?

Comment: It's only needed for the middle bijection. You need to assign a bijection $\pi^{-1}(b)\cong F$ to each $b\in B$.

Comment: I think a choice-free proof of the application is to identify $F$-bundles over $B$ with elements of the nonabelian cohomology set $\check{H}^1(B, Homeo(F))$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm skeptical that a complete proof along those lines could be done without choice. I'll happily accept that a bundle comes with a distinguished atlas (which I have not assumed), but I think that even defining $\check H^1(B,Homeo(F))$ will require choosing e.g. refinement maps for open covers, and any manipulation to connect it with the theory of bundles will require choosing representative cocycles for its cohomology classes.